# Prove $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complete-spaces

I'm struggling with an exercise in my real analysis course. The question it asks is:

Prove that $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ with the metric induced by $\left\Vert \cdot \right\Vert_{\infty} $ is complete. (Where $\left\Vert M \right\Vert_{\infty} :=\max\{m_{ij}\,|\,1\leq i \leq n, 1\leq j \leq n\} $

Edit note: I am generally struggling with this concept as a whole, so also any advice on how to tackle problems in this topic of a similar nature would be very much appreciated

Comment: How do you prove anything is complete? You want to show that a cauchy sequence is a convergent sequence with a limit point which is an element of the space. So, consider a cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and show that it converges to a point in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. What does it mean to be a cauchy sequence in this space with this norm?

Comment: @CRB: Here, I assume that $M$ is an $m\times n $ matrix?

Comment: @Idonknow yes, it is, sorry if I didn't make it very clear

Comment: @TonyS.F. This is sort of the bit I am struggling with. Unfortunately real analysis is not my strongest subject 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\bigl(M(n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence of matrices. Then, for each $i$ and each $j$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, each sequence $\bigl(M(n)_{ij}\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers, since$$\bigl|M(m)_{ij}-M(n)_{ij}\bigr|\leqslant\bigl\|M(m)-M(n)\bigr\|$$for each $m,n\in\mathbb N$ and since $\bigl(M(n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let $M_{ij}=\lim_{n\to\infty}M_{ij}(n)$ and let $M=(M_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$. Then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}M_n=M.$$